# Issue with selecting max id rows using criteria query / hibernate query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am unable to select the rows where TestId is max for respective student, I wrote the code as follows which does not get the required output. my code is as follows,

```
Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(student.class).setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("answer"),"answer"));
c.add(Restrictions.eq("surveyId",send_Survey));
//c.add(Restrictions.eq("testId", "1" ));
//c.setProjection(Projection.max("testId"));
c.addOrder(Order.desc("testId"));
c.add(Restrictions.eq("questionid",FinalQuestionsOne));
List<String> age=c.list();
```

My table structure is as follows,

[image]

I need the following output. select the answer column for max TestId's. How can I get the output using criteria query

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I think what you're trying to get can be achievedd by the following sql:

```
SELECT TestId, MAX(answer) WHERE questionId = 1 GROUP BY TestId;
```

You should be able to achieve this with the following Hibernate:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(student.class).setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.property("TestId"), "TestId")
                        .add(Projections.groupProperty("TestId"))
                        .add(Projections.max("answer")));
```

Comment: Can't it be possible with Detached criteria?

Comment: @Manju I don't see you using `DetachedCriteria` explicitly in your question?