# Issue with writing a criteria /hibernate query?

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

How can we write the following sql query in criteria query and also in hibernate query?

sql query follows,

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY testId DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I wrote as follows,

```
Criteria tobaccoID = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(table1.class);
tobaccoID.add(Restrictions.eq("surveyId",send_Survey));
tobaccoID.addOrder(Order.desc("testId")); // How can I specify the limit 1 here
tobaccoID.add(Restrictions.eq("algorithmno", lifeStyleHabbitsOne));
tobaccoID.add(Restrictions.eq("stringno", "01"));
ScrollableResults tobaccoIDP=tobaccoID.scroll();
```

But I don't know how can I set the limit here.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Something like `coID.setMaxResults(1);`

Comment: It does not work for my requirement. I have clearly explained my question in the following link. Please give me suggestion to do that.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489359/issue-with-selecting-max-id-rows-using-criteria-query-hibernate-query